# Getting all the min elements and its indices from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list that has a minimum element that is present multiple times like

```
a = [1,2,1,1,4,5,6]
```

And I want Python to return the element `1` and all the indices in the list where `1` is present. I tried using

```
min_index, min_value = min(enumerate(a), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

which gives only the index where `1` occurs first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

determine the minimum element, and then check it against other elements in the list.

```
def locate_min(a):
    smallest = min(a)
    return smallest, [index for index, element in enumerate(a) 
                      if smallest == element]
```

which will return a tuple (min_element, [location, location, ...]).  If I understand you correctly, this is what I think you want.  For your example:

```
>>> locate_min([1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6])
(1, [0, 2, 3])
```

This example uses a list comprehension.  If you're not familiar with this, it's roughly equivalent to the following for-loop version. (use the first version, this is just to help your understanding of how it works)

```
def locate_min(a):
    min_indicies = []
    smallest = min(a)
    for index, element in enumerate(a):
        if smallest == element: # check if this element is the minimum_value
            min_indicies.append(index) # add the index to the list if it is

    return smallest, min_indicies
```

Answer (score 20):

I'd just do it like this:

```
minimum = min(a)
indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v == minimum]
```

Answer (score 1):

The examples given loop through the list twice, once to find the `min` and again to find all that match it. In the case where the comparison is expensive or it's a very large data set, you may wish to perform a single loop. Here's an example how:

```
def locate_min(a):
    enumerated_iter = enumerate(a)

    index, min_value = next(enumerated_iter)
    indexes = [index]

    for index, value in enumerated_iter:
        if value == min_value:
            indexes.append(index)
        elif value < min_value:
            min_value = value
            indexes = [index]

    return min_value, indexes
```

`enumerate` is an iterator. This allows the use of `next` to 'pop' the first value from the sequence to prime the search. It can then be used in a `for` loop to continue on.