# Making a new list that returns the minimum value digits' position/index from the previous list

Tags: python

Make a function called positions_lowest(lorig1), with at least one element,  with integer numbers, possibly repeated,  and returns a new list (lpos) containing the positions where the minimum number is in the original list.

For example:

```
lorig=[10,2,-3,34.5, 22,-3,1]
lres = positions_lowest(lorig)
print(lres)
# gives the output:
[2, 5] # because the minimum digit is -3 and positions are 2 and 5
```

I tried many times fixing my code and it is becoming more and more complicated for this simple question, below is my code. It does not even execute

```
def positions_lowest(lorig):
    lpos = []
    if lorig:
        min_val = lorig[0]
        [(i,j) for i,val in enumerate(lorig) if j < min_val]
        if j == min_j:
            lpos.append(i)
        else: 
            min_val = j
            lpos = [i]
        return lpos
```

Comment: What do you mean *"does not even execute"*? Also why do you build then completely ignore a list using a list comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

Try to split the problem into two steps - finding the minimum element and then returning all indices of the minimum element. This will make the problem easier in my opinion. There is a built-in function for the first step - [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
In [1]: a = [10, 2, -3, 34.5, 22, -3, 1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
In [2]: minv = min(a)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# minv is now -3
```

Now try using a list comprehension to get all indices of `minv`. I think you are on the right path. You should use enumerate over the list (to be able to get the indices) and then compare each value to `minv`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not my answer, its from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15098701/12128167
You will have to make changes if you want different variable names or formats but this is
sweet and simple.

```
a = [10,2,-3,34.5, 22,-3,1]
def locate_min(a):
    smallest = min(a)
    return smallest, [index for index, element in enumerate(a)
                      if smallest == element]
print(locate_min(a))
```

Output:

```
(-3, [2, 5])
```

where -3 is the minimum number and the list of elements shows the index of the minimum number.

**IF YOU DON'T WANT MINIMUM**

```
 return [index for index, element in enumerate(a)
                          if smallest == element]
```

Change code like above.

Gives you:

```
[2, 5]
```